# Error: main class logger.MainLogger not found or loaded

Tags: java, exception, compiler-errors

```
package logger;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainLogger {

    static PrintStream log;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        VentanaLogger ventana = new VentanaLogger();
        
        try {
            log = new PrintStream( new FileOutputStream( "logger.log" , true) ); 

        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println( "Error" + e);
        }
        log.println( "Inicio Logger "  + (new Date()) );
        
        
        ventana.setVisible( true );
    }

}
```

I dont know why, but after doing this simple code, Eclipse told me "Error: main class logger.MainLogger not found or loaded" and the main, as you can see, is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but package names are usually in lowercase (logger not Logger), maybe this is the issue.

Comment: No, the problem perisits.